# Will PHP 8 do any problems in IIS?

Tags: iis, php-8

I know that Microsoft will not support PHP 8 in Internet Information Services. I successfully ran PHP 8 in IIS by adding php.exe to the Mapping Handler. PHP is working fine and my question is whether it will cause any problems in the future?

Comment: No one knows. But if there is a problem, it's guaranteed that it _won't_ be fixed. I guess you need to decide whether you should move to a supported platform. Maybe a different web server will support it. Maybe you should package a supported platform up in docker

Comment: I think bug/problem is inevitable in future and you will be difficult to get support if meet any problem. So I suggest you to consider switch with another alternative or if you still want to use PHP 8, you can just get support from limited sources.

Answer (score 2):

Problems are always expected, as no software is bug free. However, if you run PHP 8 on IIS/Windows, you will receive no technical support services from Microsoft (what you already knew), and you will have to,

- Support yourself by mastering everything about PHP/Windows,
- Or rely on the PHP open source community to help (which can be slow and without guarantee),
- Or buy commercial support services from a PHP vendor (such as Zend https://www.zend.com/products/zendphp-enterprise).